# How to configure a Dynamic Redirect on Form Submission based on Form Input

Tags: pardot

I have a pardot form (in an iframe on my landing page) with a custom drop down field where a user can select Product A or Product B. On form submission, I would like to redirect the user to thank-you-page-a or thank-you-page-b based on their selection.

I found this documentation but it does not seem to be working correctly:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383490&type=1

I have added this script to the thank you code, but the redirect is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
switch('{{Recipient.custom_field_name}}') { 
case 'Product A': parent.location='https://www.domain.com/thank-you/'; 
break; 
case 'Product B': parent.location='https://option.website.com/demo'; 
break; 
} 
</script>
```

Note: I have changed the field name "custom_field_name" and URLs here for anonymity. We are using Handlebars Merge Language.